# Understanding an exercise in K&R

Tags: c, unix, ascii

This program is the exercise from K&R book The C Programming Language:

*Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NONBLANK 'a'

int main(void)
{
      int c, lastc;

      lastc = NONBLANK;
      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
            if ( c != ' ')
                putchar(c);
            if ( c == ' ')
                if (lastc != ' ')
                    putchar(c);

            lastc = c;

            }
       } 
}
```

I just want to know how this program operates in boring details.

Comment: debug it step by step

Comment: Bit early for homework. But why not read the book?

Comment: @EdHeal Not necessarily homework, she reads K&R.

Comment: Formatted text is easier to read.

Comment: Might not be homework per se. But most (if not all) books have exercises at the end of the chapter to ensure you understand that chapter and the preceding ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop continues to execute as long as it gets a character from `stdin` that is not `EOF`:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Two `char` variables are declared: `c` and `lastc`.  For this logic to work, the current character and the previous character must be known.  Initially, `lastc` does not have a value, but it's used nonetheless:

```
if(lastc != ' ')
    putchar(c);
```

It is possible that when the program starts `lastc` will have a garbage value that `!= ' '`.  It would be a very good idea to define this variable when you declare it to a sane value:

```
int c, lastc = ' ';
```

The logic is as follows:

The current character is read from `stdin`.  If it is not the space character (`' '`), it is written to `stdout`.  If it is a space, the space is written to `stdout` only if the previous character was not a space.  If the previous character was a space, the current space is ignored as to make only one space printed if there is a series of space characters in `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

Hum. Exercise ? Boring details ?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define NONBLANK 'a'               /* a fake char to use later */
    main()
    {
      int c, lastc;

      lastc = NONBLANK;                /* now last c == char 'a' */
      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){  /* parse input (stdin), char by char */
        if ( c != ' ')                 /* if the char is a *not* a space ..*/
        putchar(c);                    /* then write it on stdout; */
        if ( c == ' ')                 /* if it is a space ..*/
          if (lastc != ' ')            /*.. and lastc is *not* a space ..*/
            putchar(c);                /* then write it on stdout; */
        lastc = c;                     /* Make lastc be equal to the current */
                                       /* parsed char, and loop up to while */
      }
   }
```

PS: fisrt time Here.. Sorry for the formatting mess.

HTH

-- 
michel marcon (aka cmic)